# Get an array of symbols from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with text inside curlies like this:

```
{field1}-{field}+{field3}Anthing{field4}
```

from which I need to get an array like this:

```
['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
```

Is there a way to do it using regexes in c#?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to split on "+" and trim the leading and trailing brace from each item?

Comment: Do you also want `feild2` to be spelt incorrectly? If so, then this might be very difficult ;P

Comment: @Old Man - You wrote a comment on the deleted answer: "separator could be anything" . You should edit the question to clarify that, and add better examples.

Comment: To add to what Kobi said, if the "separator could be anything", then you're going to have a tougher time.  This is especially true if it can be different *within the same string*, because you will have to handle balancing of curly-braces.  This will drastically impact what could be considered a correct answer.

Comment: Can you have escaped `{`, or non-matching `{`/`}`? For example: `+\{+{field}`, or `+}+{fi{eld}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Split and Linq:

```
string[] words = s.Split('+')
                  .Select(word => word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2))
                  .ToArray();
```

Or, you can match for `{...}` tokens using a simple regular expression:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\{(\w*)\}");
string[] words = matches.Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

`\w*` would only match alphanumeric characters, you may want to replace it with `[^}]*` or `.*?`.

Answer (score 1):

like this ? ↓

```
　　static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string from = "{field1}+{field2}+{field3}";
        string[] to = from.Split("{}+".ToCharArray() , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

        foreach (var x in to)
            Console.WriteLine(x);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**FOR EDIT**

- To solve the problem with "{field1}-{field}+{field3}Anthing{field4} "

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      string f = "{field1}-{field}+{field3}Anthing{field4} ";
      List<string> lstPattern = new List<string>();
      foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(f, "{.*?}"))
      {
          lstPattern.Add(m.Value.Replace("{","").Replace("}",""));
      }

      foreach (var p in lstPattern)
          Console.WriteLine(p);

  }
  ```